# What are `(QWidget* pobj=0)` and `(QWidget* pwgt/*=0/)` for?

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, qwidget

I have just started to learn QT. Can't understand how do theese constructors work. For example:

```
//Progress.h
#include<QtWidgets>
class QProgressBar;
class Progress:public QWidget{
Q_OBJECT
private:
QProgressBar* m_pprb;
int step;
public:
Progress(QWidget* pobj=0);
public slots:
void slotStep();
void slotReset();
//

//Progress.cpp
#include<QtWidgets>
#include"Progress.h"
 Progress::Progress(QWidget* pwgt/*=0*/):QWidget(pwgt)
{
//some buttons
}
```

So, the question is, what happens in constructors?

Comment: Please post all code, this won't compile

Comment: Read about default argument values in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: You left out a `*`  in `/*=0/`. In the actual code, it is a comment: `/*=0*/`.

Comment: And the `;` seems to be wrong in the 4th last line

Comment: Side note: Be aware that Qt is designed such that parents will clean up all children by themselves. So unless you don't set the parent, you don't have to care for deleting created objects – apart from the root object, which usually is a `QApplication` object.

Comment: Is your question perhaps on why name `pobj` in the .h file and `pwgt` in the .cpp, perhaps leading you to use the plural form "constructors"?

Answer (score 2):

What you are creating is a `Progress`class which inherits from [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html).

The QWidget class *can* take an `parent`argument, if you look at the documentation:

> Constructs a widget which is a child of parent, with widget flags set to f. If parent is nullptr, the new widget becomes a window. If parent is another widget, this widget becomes a child window inside parent. The new widget is deleted when its parent is deleted.

This `parent`in your code is called `pwgt` (I would think it stands for `parentWidget`)

What you do, is creating a default argument for your constructor to be set automatic to 0:

```
Progress(QWidget* pobj=0);
```

*Cleaner* maybe would be (for convenience with Qt standard):

```
Progress(QWidget* parent=nullptr);
```

So, why do do you need the constructor to look like this?
It is the same reason, which stands for `QWidget`:
You *can* set a parent widget, but you **don't** have to!
The `QWidget` class will deal for you with this, either you set a parent or not.

Comment: Not fully sure, but I think Qt is still compatible to C++98/03, thus 0 and not nullptr...

Comment: @Aconcagua not sure about this, but I meant to use the same *style* as Qt, so if you look at the sources, you will find `nullptr` Therefore I always use the same *interface* with the same variable names and parameters

Comment: Ah, I see, you were referring to the custom constructor. Agree, nullptr is better there, unless you have backwards compatibility requrirements as well...

Comment: @RoQuOTriX And what about a `QList<int> what_ever` in the class? Can I be 100% sure that an instance of `what_ever` is ready to be used and has 0 elements?

Comment: @G.Vanem strange that you ask this question on this comment, but yes you are right. You can use any objects you want in the qt classes as like in a custom class. If you use the `QList` it will be size 0. I am not sure what you mean with ready to use. I think you are confused about pointers and values

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Ment just that; "ready to be used" == size 0.